# how to remove all space on indent when inserting a newline under vim Xcode

Tags: xcode, vim

I am new to Xcode and use vim for my editor under Xcode. How to use `shift + O` to add newline in vim under Xcode without adding space as indent?

so I will not have lots of space in blank line like following during `git diff`

[image]

this is what I expect during `git diff`
[image]

Comment: SwiftFormat can help: https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat

Answer (score 11):

1. Go to Xcode Preferences.
2. Choose Text Editing tab.
3. Switch to the Editing page underneath.
4. Check both "Automatically trim trailing whitespace" and "Including whitespace-only lines".

This works both in Vim mode and the normal mode.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode's Text Editing Preferences]